# CIFS mount - changing permissions on file doesnt take an effect

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs

I can't change permissions on files which are mounted with cifs from windows share. I can only change write permission.

I mounted share using:

```
//10.0.0.1/share on /some/path/to/folder
type cifs (rw,username=usr,password=passwd,domain=10.0.0.1,uid=32,gid=1001,
iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0770,sec=ntlm,_netdev)
```

Where uid is my username.

When I try to change permission of some file inside share, like /some/path/to/folder/simple/file.inside to 777:

```
sudo chmod 777 file.inside
```

Permssions doesnt change to 777 instead `ls -l` output gives `-rwxr-xr-x`

When I change it to 000 result is: `-r-xr-xr-x`

The only difference between those two is that owner is not allowed to write. I am confused why is that and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html#id2532725

> The core CIFS protocol does not provide unix ownership information or mode for files and directories. Because of this, files and directories will generally appear to be owned by whatever values the uid= or gid= options are set, and will have permissions set to the default file_mode and dir_mode for the mount. **Attempting to change these values via chmod/chown will return success but have no effect**.

Therefore, it's not implemented yet.