# Changing permissions on CIFS files and folders from a Linux client

Tags: linux, cifs, active-directory

I'm using an Ubuntu 18.04 workstation in a corporate enviroment that is mostly windows based. The workstation has joined the Active Directory environment using pbis-open, and several shares are automounted on logon. This works for my day-to-day needs.

One thing I'm missing, however, it the ability to change user access rights and permissions on the NAS file share from my Ubuntu workstation. I currently need to use a Windows workstation or Windows VM to do this.

I've read the mount.cifs manpage, which says that chmod/chown will simply return success but won't actually change anything (I picked that up from [CIFS mount - changing permissions on file doesnt take an effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372947/cifs-mount-changing-permissions-on-file-doesnt-take-an-effect)). That's fine, though, I'm more looking for a way to add or remove permissions for domain users and groups.

Has anyone got this working? Is mounting with the flag "cifsacl" and setting up cifs.idmap part of the solution?

Note, I'm not looking for a solution where multiple users will be accessing the same mount from my workstation. I simply want access to grant/revoke windows permissions to specific users and groups from my Linux workstation.

Comment: Just to be clear: The data you are trying to protect / control access to, is on your machine, or somewhere in the network?

Comment: I want to set/change permissions on files on a NAS. I currently have to use a Windows machine to change these permissions. I'll update the question to clarify.